# Why .findall in xml file doesn't read correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-3.6, elementtree

Let's take a look at the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root
    xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <URLBase>http://192.168.1.1:80</URLBase>
    <device>
        <serviceList>
            <service>
                <serviceType>1</serviceType>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
        <deviceList>
            <device>
                <serviceList>
                    <service>
                        <serviceType>2</serviceType>
                    </service>
                </serviceList>
                <deviceList>
                    <device>
                        <serviceList>
                            <service>
                                <serviceType>3</serviceType>
                            </service>
                        </serviceList>
                    </device>
                </deviceList>
            </device>
        </deviceList>
        <presentationURL>/</presentationURL>
    </device>
</root>
```

I want to extract all services under `device` so in the example it should be only 1.

So I wrote:

```
import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(inner_xml) #inner_xml=above
device = root.find('{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}device')
for serviceType in device.findall(
        './/{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceList//{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceType'):
    print(serviceType.text)
```

But why I'm getting 2 and 3 too? They aren't in `serviceList` directly under `device`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have a problem, always post complete copy-pastable code (see [mcve]), including `import` statements. Don't just post code fragments.

Comment: @mzjn Done, please take a look

Comment: An expression such as `.//x` selects all `x` descendants of the context node. In your case, the context node is the `device` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code "asks" to do a recursive search by using `//`

```
for serviceType in device.findall(
        './/{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceList//{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceType'):
```

You need to use

```
for serviceType in device.findall(
        '{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceList//{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceType'):
```

working code below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root
    xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <URLBase>http://192.168.1.1:80</URLBase>
    <device>
        <serviceList>
            <service>
                <serviceType>1</serviceType>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
        <deviceList>
            <device>
                <serviceList>
                    <service>
                        <serviceType>2</serviceType>
                    </service>
                </serviceList>
                <deviceList>
                    <device>
                        <serviceList>
                            <service>
                                <serviceType>3</serviceType>
                            </service>
                        </serviceList>
                    </device>
                </deviceList>
            </device>
        </deviceList>
        <presentationURL>/</presentationURL>
    </device>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
device = root.find('{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}device')
for serviceType in device.findall(
        '{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceList//{urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0}serviceType'):
    print(serviceType.text)
```

Comment: Just declare `namespaces = {"": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0"}` and pass it as second argument to all find functions, it'll shorten your XPath.

Comment: What do u mean by recursive? inside what?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple XPath `./device/serviceList/service/serviceType` to find nodes. Also you can pass namespaces as second argument to any find function to not specify them for each node in XPath expression. You can read more about this here: [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces).

**Code:**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

source = ...
root = ET.fromstring(source)

namespaces = {"": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0"}
for node in root.iterfind("./device/serviceList/service/serviceType", namespaces):
    print(node.text)
```

Comment: what is the difference between .// and ./?

Comment: @Algo, it's described in [Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) article of XPath standard. Basically, `./node` will search for `<node>` which is child node of root while `.//node` will search for `<node>` which is child node of any other node inside root (recursively). E.g. XPath expression from my answer can be shorten to `./device/serviceList//serviceType`, but not `./device//serviceType` as it will find all `<serviceType>` nodes incide `<device>`. Is it more clear now or some extended explanation required?